# Azure Tables async query filter with a 'take' is not giving top #n entities

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I want the top 100 entities (most recent) out of several thousand entities matching my TableQuery filter and I attempted it in two ways:

1. The first attempt was to use an index counter in the `foreach` loop to break once it reached "100". This gave me a strange random subset of data with most of it missing and not 100 entities; more like several hundred and not an even number.
2. The second attempt is pasted below and essentially ignores my continuation token and also sets the `.take` to "100". This gives me exactly the number of entities matching the take integer however many entities are missing.

Each attempt gives different results back and I think I know why but I don't know how to fix it to get back what I need. I realize setting a query filter on the timestamp is not great for performance reasons (it's not indexed...right?). So should I populate another field with a date/time value to filter off of?

```
        public async Task<List<ActivityModel>> GetActivitiesAsync(string DomainName, string NodeId, string ComputerName)
    {
        List<ActivityModel> activities = new List<ActivityModel>();
        CloudTable cloudTable = TableConnection("NodeEvents");
        string domainFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("DomainName", QueryComparisons.Equal, DomainName);
        string nodeIdFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, NodeId);
        string computerNameFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("ComputerName", QueryComparisons.Equal, ComputerName);
        string filter1 = TableQuery.CombineFilters(domainFilter, TableOperators.And, nodeIdFilter);
        string filter2 = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter1, TableOperators.And, computerNameFilter);
        TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

        var result = await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<ActivityModel>().Where(filter2).Take(100), continuationToken);

        if (result.Results != null)
        {
            foreach (ActivityModel entity in result.Results)
            {
                activities.Add(entity);
            }
        }

        return activities;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to **Log Tail Pattern** in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#log-tail-pattern).

> Retrieve the *n* entities most recently added to a partition by using a **RowKey** value that sorts in reverse date and time order.
>
> **Context and problem**
>
> A common requirement is to be able to retrieve the most recently created entities, for example the ten most recent expense claims submitted by an employee. Table queries support a **$top** query operation to return the first *n* entities from a set: there is no equivalent query operation to return the last *n* entities in a set.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Store the entities using a **RowKey** that naturally sorts in reverse date/time order by using so the most recent entry is always the first one in the table.
>
> For example, to be able to retrieve the ten most recent expense claims submitted by an employee, you can use a reverse tick value derived from the current date/time. The following C# code sample shows one way to create a suitable "inverted ticks" value for a **RowKey** that sorts from the most recent to the oldest:

```
string invertedTicks = string.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
```

> You can get back to the date time value using the following code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - Int64.Parse(invertedTicks));
```

> The table query looks like this:

```
https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/EmployeeExpense(PartitionKey='empid')?$top=10
```

> **Issues and considerations**
>
> Consider the following points when deciding how to implement this pattern:
>
> - You must pad the reverse tick value with leading zeroes to ensure the
>   string value sorts as expected.
> - You must be aware of the scalability targets at the level of a partition. Be careful not create hot spot partitions.

Comment: Given this example, is there an equivalent 'top' for the Azure Storage Client Library?